# Get and display checked checkbox index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to display the checkbox position when the user check the checkbox every time using Jquery. For example, when user check Monday, it will display position 0 and when user check Sunday, it will display position 6. I could not find a way to do it. I have tried to use .index() but it keep showing me 0. Any idea on how to do it?

HTML code

```
<div class="col-sm-9 checkbox_days">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Monday"> Monday
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">    
        <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Tuesday"> Tuesday
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Wednesday"> Wednesday
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Thursday"> Thursday
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">                        
        <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Friday"> Friday
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">                        
        <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Saturday"> Saturday
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">                        
        <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Sunday"> Sunday
    </label>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('.day').on('change', function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            alert($(this).index());
        } else {
            alert("unchecked");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove `$(this).each(function(){` you don't need that

Comment: If you remove the labels it should works. Like this the checkboxes are no siblings. At least with your selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`.index(element)`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element) to find elements index in the list.

```
$('.day').index(this)
```

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.day').on('change', function() {

    if (this.checked) {
      alert($('.day').index(this));
    } else {
      alert("unchecked");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-9 checkbox_days">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Monday">Monday
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Tuesday">Tuesday
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Wednesday">Wednesday
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Thursday">Thursday
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Friday">Friday
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Saturday">Saturday
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Sunday">Sunday
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out the parent's index. Use `closest()` in order to get the particular parent.

```
$('.day').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).closest(".ui-checkbox").index() + 1);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/64/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a click capturing event for simplicity:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    alert($('input[type="checkbox"]').index(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
 if (this.checked) {
     alert($(this).parent('label').index());
 }
```

instead of

```
  $(this).each(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            alert($(this).index());
        } 
    });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rsbt8dx1/):

If you want your checkboxes to be mutually checked , then here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rsbt8dx1/1/):

Answer (score 0):

```js
var map = {
        'Monday': 0,
        'Tuesday': 1,
        'Wednesday': 2,
        'Thursday': 3,
        'Friday': 4,
        'Saturday': 5,
        'Sunday': 6
}
$('.day').on('change', function () {

    if (this.checked) {
        alert(map[$(this).val()]);
    } else {
        alert("unchecked");
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-9 checkbox_days">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Monday">Monday</label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Tuesday">Tuesday</label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Wednesday">Wednesday</label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Thursday">Thursday</label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Friday">Friday</label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Saturday">Saturday</label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="Sunday">Sunday</label>
</div>
```

you can use a save the state in some variable and use it

Answer (score 0):

$('input:checkbox').click( function() {
    var selectedIndex = $('input:checkbox').index( $(this) );

alert(selectedIndex);
});

Answer (score 0):

You are placed a checkbox in separate div for each, so it always returns 0 as index. Try to get a index of parent node like below

```
 alert($(this).parent('.checkbox').index() + 1);
 or
 alert($(this).parent().index() + 1);
```